# How to display multiple phone numbers for the same person in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm trying to display multiple numbers in flutter app using `contact_service`
The way I do it is to make a map with key-value pairs where the name is the key and the number is the value and I had no problem with it,[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsVuP.png).

But how can I display these numbers for the person when the same person might have more than one number?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some of the code that you are using so I can understand the structure of that same image?

You need to make a `ListView.builder()`. With that widget, you can define the number of elements with the map length, and in each element, iterate through the values.